# How to delete data from fields in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue that I am facing.
I have a text in the text box that I want to delete, the problem is that

```
driver.find_element_by_id('foo').clear()
```

not work and I need something harder than this clear function that do nothing.
I used this mthood that actually worked in windows:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

if I want it to run on mac and on Linux machine, how can I perform it?

please the clear() not worked please do not provide solution with the clear() method

Comment: What tag is `driver.find_element_by_id('foo')`?

Answer (score 2):

Use execute_script:

element=driver.find_element_by_id('foo');
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=' ';", element);

Answer (score 0):

1. try

   driver.findElement(yourelement).sendKeys("");
2. or variant

   ```
   use Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   // ...  // may be move cursor to field
   action.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT);
   action.build().perform();
   ```

may be problem in selenium library error, or in the webdriver version,
or conflict with js-framework on a form?

Answer (score 0):

i use this also

```
public void clearAndInputStringData(By locator, String text) throws Exception {
        ClickElementWhenClickable(locator);
        WebElement element = getWebDriver().findElement(locator);
       // element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
        Actions actions = new Actions(getWebDriver());
        actions.doubleClick(element).perform();
        element.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
        element.sendKeys(text);
    }
```